# pandas `styler.to_html()` - how to hide only columns index names

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas

In most cases, my DataFrame has index names, but it doesn't have columns index names. When trying to bump it to HTML, instead of having single row in header (indexNames, columnsNames), I have two rows where first contains columns names (and columns index name which is empty in my case) and second one contains only index names and blank cells. I want to convert it to single row which should contains both index names and columns names. I don't want to use `reset_index()`. I know that there is `styler.hide(names  = True)` method but it hides index names instead of columns index names. What can I do? Or maybe currently I can only edit it afterwards with the sue of regex??